# Explicit derivation of free scalar stress-energy tensor $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have derived by varying the following action

$$
\mathcal{S}_{free} = \int d^4x\sqrt{-g} \left( -g^{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{2}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu \phi - V(\phi)\right)
$$
the following stress-energy tensor
$$
T_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}\nabla_\rho\phi\nabla_\sigma \phi-g_{\mu\nu}V(\phi)
$$
with the equation of motion as 
$$
\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\phi-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}=0
$$

I'm trying to explicitly show that $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$ using the e.o.m but I just can't seem to figure this out! My problem is getting $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ to have an expression which is the e.o.m multiplied with something so that it is shown to be zero.

What I've tried:
$$
\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu\left(\nabla^\mu\phi\nabla^\nu\phi+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}\nabla_\rho\phi\nabla_\sigma\phi+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}V(\phi)\right)
$$
$$
=(\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\phi)\nabla^\nu\phi+(\nabla_\mu\nabla^\nu\phi)\nabla^\mu\phi+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\rho\phi)\nabla_\sigma\phi+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\sigma\phi)\nabla_\rho\phi+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu( V (\phi))
$$

Edit:

I've arrived using the hints below to 
$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=
\nabla_\mu\nabla^\nu\phi\nabla^\mu\phi-\nabla^\nu\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla^\mu\phi
$$

Is it correct to assume $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\nu\phi = \nabla^\nu\nabla_\mu\phi$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have added the bit that I have tried on the question. @Prahar

Comment: You can use the chain rule for the $\nabla_\mu(V(\phi))$ term and the symmetry of $g^{\sigma \rho}$.

Comment: Your algebra is correct. For the last point - you know the explicit definition of covariant derivative right? Why don’t you use that to check whether what you need is correct?

Comment: Oh thanks, yeah I checked it and it turns out to be correct since $\Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\mu} = \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\alpha}$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\nabla^{α}(\nabla_{α}φ\nabla_{β}φ) -\cfrac{1}{2}g_{αβ}g^{μν}\nabla^{α}(\nabla_{μ}φ\nabla_{ν}φ) - \nabla^{α}g_{αβ}V(φ) = 0 \Rightarrow $
$\nabla^{α}\nabla_{α}φ\nabla_{β}φ +\nabla_{α}φ \nabla^{α}\nabla_{β}φ - \cfrac{1}{2}g_{αβ}g^{μν}\nabla^{α}(\nabla_{μ}φ)\nabla_{ν}φ -  \cfrac{1}{2}g_{αβ}g^{μν}\nabla_{μ}φ\nabla^{α}\nabla_{ν}φ - \nabla^{α}g_{αβ}V(φ) = 0 \Rightarrow$ 
$\nabla^{α}\nabla_{α}φ\nabla_{β}φ +\nabla_{α}φ \nabla^{α}\nabla_{β}φ - \cfrac{1}{2}\nabla_{β}(\nabla^{ν}φ)\nabla_{ν}φ - \cfrac{1}{2}\nabla_{β}(\nabla^{μ}φ)\nabla_{μ}φ - \nabla_{β}φ\cfrac{dV}{dφ} = 0 \Rightarrow $
$\nabla^{α}\nabla_{α}φ\nabla_{β}φ - \nabla_{β}φ\cfrac{dV}{dφ} = 0\Rightarrow $
$\nabla_{β}φ ( \nabla^{α}\nabla_{α}φ - \cfrac{dV}{dφ}) = 0 $

Since $\nabla_{β}φ = 0 \rightarrow φ = $ constant , $\nabla^{α}\nabla_{α}φ - \cfrac{dV}{dφ} =0$